# How to identify this mysterious Windows service

Tags: windows, malware

The name of the service is a 32-digit hex number. It might be randomly generated, since a Google search on the number did not find anything. It points to an EXE file which also has a hex number as name, in a folder which also have a hex number as name.

I suspect this could some kind of malware, since the naming looks so strange, but a malware scan did not flag it. It might also be legitimate software which just have strange names for some reason.

In the Details-tab of the EXE file properties, the file description is blank, but there is a product version ("3.13.11.3") and Copyright ("Copyright (C) 2014") which doesn't help me a lot.

The question is: How do I identify what program the service actually is, since the file names do not give any clue?

Comment: The properties of the .exe file should show some information about the author, name, version etc. in the Details tab ... at least for legitimate applications.

Comment: Maybe try this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx and see which process is using that .exe?

Comment: @Mugurel: Thank you for the suggestion, but I have stopped and disabled the service until I am sure it is legitimate software.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: File description is blank, but there is a product version and copyright which doesn't tell me a lot.

Comment: If it's a CLSID, you can search for it in the registry. A CLSID looks like this: ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C

Comment: It sounds very suspicious ... if I were you I'd [nuke the server from orbit](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) and restore backups.

Comment: Did you try uploading the file to virustotal.com for a broader scan? But in general I agree with Gerald Schneider. Take the server off the network, restore it and check other Servers / Clients for suspicious files / processes and activities.

Comment: @adiuva: Thanks, this helped me identify the software - it was a well-known adware. If you write this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: I suggest trying to decompile the EXE to search for more details using something like Resource Hacker http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try uploading the file to [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com) for a broader scan?
But in general I agree with Gerald Schneider. Take the server off the network, restore it and check other Servers / Clients for suspicious files / processes and activities.